# How to avoid big data problem when dealing nii.gz?

Tags: python, numpy, nifti, nibabel

I have dataset of `nii.gz` files each around `1G` including `4d` tensor. There are two ways of reading them that I am aware of as the following:

```
img = nib.load('fMRI.nii.gz')
imgarr = np.array(img.dataobj)
```

or

```
img = nib.load('fMRI.nii.gz')
imgarr = img.get_data()
```

the problem is reading the whole tensor is expensive and I just need an slice. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

Actually you do not need to load anything of the main image **data** into the memory.

```
img = nib.load('fMRI.nii.gz')
 
# get the first 10 slices
img.slicer[0:10]

#verify selection
img.slicer[0:10].shape
```